# Handle Keyboard Keys ALT+F4 combination in Java

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am a windows user and i don't want to close my jframe when I press
<kbd>ALT+F4</kbd>,

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
 if (KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK){
 }
}
```

get the keystrokes and handle/stop closing or switching of the jframe

so how can i handle this keypressed combination in java,
please help....

Comment: *"i am a windows user and i don't want to close my jframe when i press 'ALT+F4',"*  So don't press Alt+F4.  When it comes to *other people's computers,* don't stuff with the usual functionality they expect (otherwise it will be Ctrl+Alt+Del for that app.).

Comment: *"i don't want to close my jframe when i press 'ALT+F4'"* Why not? This is what the system defined key binding is. What if you don't want the `K` key to print `K`, but `E` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the previous will lock closing if indeed you press the key combination meaning there on even close X will not work. hence the  following 
REVIEW: much better based on  fast snail answer:

```
public class OnKeyAltF4DontClose2 extends JFrame {//implements  WindowListener {

public OnKeyAltF4DontClose2() {
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    setBounds(400,400,400,400);



    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            if(((KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK)) != null)  &&  e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F4){

            e.consume();
            }

            }

    });

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new OnKeyAltF4DontClose2();

}
```

}

Comment: (1) `setDefaultCloseOperation` should use a Swing constant value, not the equivalent `int`. (2) `setVisible` should be called last. (3) `pack` is preferable to `setBounds` unless there is a good reason for it. (4) *"even close X will not work"* a *very* bad idea AND not what the OP wants.

Comment: working fine from my end! @user1803551 thanks for the point outs, though the concern was the task at hand. you are right setVisible should be called last, setDefa...(3) represents the Frame constant EXIT_ON_CLOSE(either way the same), finally i disagree on the pack(), since there are no, components sizing and positioning was important, and ooh! pack() is depreciated...

Comment: *"pack() is depreciated"* Where did you get this information? Do you even read the API?

Comment: task accomplished.  no stress  !?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to allow window to close when press **<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>** all you need to do is add key bindings  to child element of window .but you need to use key-bind for **<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>** press event as action listner is not able to do it.i guess because it lost focus when you press that keys. window stay without closing if it listen to press event even for **<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>**.you can add keylistner to child component like shown below.

```
childComponent.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F4, InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK), "stopclose");

childComponent.getActionMap().put("stopclose", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("i'm waiting ");
    }
});
```

and complete example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class NoExit {

    public NoExit() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        JLabel lable = new JLabel("i will not exit for your  ALT + F4 command");
        lable.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        lable.setOpaque(true);
        lable.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F4, InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK), "stopclose");
        lable.getActionMap().put("stopclose", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("i'm waiting ");
            }
        });
        f.add(lable);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NoExit();
    }

}
```

output>>

[image]