# Java - Event on the Alt-F4 pressing

Tags: java, action, shutdown

I would like my program to do an action when the combination <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> is pressed, but I don't know how I can detect when these keys are pressed.

Do you guys have an idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559724/handle-keyboard-keys-altf4-combination-in-java

Comment: On windows, you program may not be notified of this key press.  You could use a shutdown hook

Comment: @MadProgrammer i'm not sure but i gave a answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559724/handle-keyboard-keys-altf4-combination-in-java and it seems to be fine

Comment: @FastSnail It could be, it's just that "system" key events don't make into the event queue

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks i'll try this out !

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks bro it worked perfectly